# How to skip creating a pydantic basemodel in case of invalid data and how to log errors with invalid data

Tags: python, pydantic

I have data in dataframe format and I want to validate that using pydantic basemodel. If there are certain rows with invalid data, I want skip those rows and validate the rest of the rows without stopping the program. I would be returning a list of validated rows. I am just providing simple example to avoid complications.

Current code is as follows

```
class Row(BaseModel):
    x: str = Field(min_length=2)
    y: str = Field(min_length=2)
    z: int = Field(gt=0, le=300001)

class RowList(BaseModel):
    rowlist: List[Row]
```

The dataframe containing data is df with columns xval, yval, zval.

```
emptyList = []
for index, value in df.iterrows():
    x1 = value['xval']
    y1 = value['yval']
    z1 = value['zval']

    row = Row(x=x1,y=y1,z=z1)
    emptyList.append(row)
```

The questions:

1. suppose I have a string in zval column, the code breaks down. How do I skip the row with erroneous data, and continue my program?
2. I want to log the error, basically the column, value, and index which threw an error so I can go back to data source and fix it.
3. completely unrelated: is there any efficient way to model since at the end of the code I need to convert the rowlist into a dataframe and use it somewhere else.

```
errordata = {}
emptyList = []
for index, value in df.iterrows():
    x1 = value['xval']
    y1 = value['yval']
    z1 = value['zval']
    row = Row(x=x1,y=y1,z=z1)
    try:
        emptyList.append(row)
    except:
        print(f"Error- ValueError {ValueError} for {index}") 
        errordata[index] = ValueError
```

I am looking for a clean and efficient way to execute the problem I face. I want to log all errors associated with each row.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, you can perform individual `Row` parsing in a custom generator function and then pass the resulting iterator to your output model with the `list[Row]` field. That way you can catch individual `Row` errors and pass on only the valid `Row` objects.

To your second question, the Pydantic [`ValidationError`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.5/pydantic/error_wrappers.py#L50) wrapper carries most of the information you mentioned about what did not pass validation and why. It has the `errors` method returning a list of the error dictionaries. If you iterate over the input data with an index alongside it, you can augment each of those error dictionaries with the index. That way you should have all you need.

Here is an example implementation:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator

from pandas import DataFrame
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ValidationError


class Row(BaseModel):
    x: str = Field(min_length=2)
    y: str = Field(min_length=2)
    z: int = Field(gt=0, le=300001)

    class Config:
        copy_on_model_validation = "none"


class Output(BaseModel):
    rows: list[Row]


def row_parser(data: DataFrame) -> Iterator[Row]:
    for idx, item in data.iterrows():
        try:
            yield Row(
                x=item["xval"],
                y=item["yval"],
                z=item["zval"],
            )
        except ValidationError as error_wrapper:
            for error in error_wrapper.errors():
                error_data = {"index": idx} | dict(error)
                print(f"Invalid row: {error_data}")  # use real logger instead
```

Demo:

```py
def test() -> None:
    test_df = DataFrame([
        {"xval": "abc", "yval": "123", "zval": 1},   # valid
        {"xval": "abc", "yval": "123", "zval": 2},   # valid
        {"xval": "a", "yval": "123", "zval": 3},     # x invalid
        {"xval": "abc", "yval": " ", "zval": 4},     # y invalid
        {"xval": "abc", "yval": "123", "zval": -1},  # z invalid
        {"xval": " ", "yval": " ", "zval": "foo"},   # all invalid
    ])
    output = Output.parse_obj({"rows": row_parser(test_df)})
    print("Output:")
    print(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Output:

```
Invalid row: {'index': 2, 'loc': ('x',), 'msg': 'ensure this value has at least 2 characters', 'type': 'value_error.any_str.min_length', 'ctx': {'limit_value': 2}}
Invalid row: {'index': 3, 'loc': ('y',), 'msg': 'ensure this value has at least 2 characters', 'type': 'value_error.any_str.min_length', 'ctx': {'limit_value': 2}}
Invalid row: {'index': 4, 'loc': ('z',), 'msg': 'ensure this value is greater than 0', 'type': 'value_error.number.not_gt', 'ctx': {'limit_value': 0}}
Invalid row: {'index': 5, 'loc': ('x',), 'msg': 'ensure this value has at least 2 characters', 'type': 'value_error.any_str.min_length', 'ctx': {'limit_value': 2}}
Invalid row: {'index': 5, 'loc': ('y',), 'msg': 'ensure this value has at least 2 characters', 'type': 'value_error.any_str.min_length', 'ctx': {'limit_value': 2}}
Invalid row: {'index': 5, 'loc': ('z',), 'msg': 'value is not a valid integer', 'type': 'type_error.integer'}
Output:
rows=[Row(x='abc', y='123', z=1), Row(x='abc', y='123', z=2)]
```

The default validators for Pydantic are fairly "smart" and lenient. Though we pass an iterator and not a list to the `Output.rows` field, the [list validator](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.5/pydantic/validators.py#L261) will coerce (in this case consume) the object to a list.

Side note: The only reason I used `parse_obj` instead of simply initializing with `Output(rows=row_parser(test_df))` is because static type checkers like mypy and PyCharm with their respective Pydantic plugins will complain that `row_parser` does not return a list. But the code would still work fine.

Since the items in our iterator are already `Row` objects **and** we set the [config parameter](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/model_config/#options) `copy_on_model_validation` to `"none"`, no further validation and data copying will happen on the `Output` model, which should make this more efficient.